# Jmeter: After configuration of proxy of my mobile wifi, internet is not getting connected

Tags: testing, proxy, load, jmeter

I have configured proxy server and port in my android mobile of my PC IP and port. But I am not able to connect internet on my mobile.
In Jmeter, Root CA Certification is install.

Let me know where I am incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was previously got connected and certification was installed in my browser. After clearing cache and cookies, I have re-installed the certification, now this working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Few assumptions:

1. Just in case, have you started JMeter's Proxy Server?
2. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to your Test Plan to see whether are any requests being sent through JMeter. If yes - it might be the case you're sitting behind the corporate proxy. See [Using JMeter behind a proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) chapter:

> If you are testing from behind a firewall/proxy server, you may need to provide JMeter with the firewall/proxy server hostname and port number. To do so, run the jmeter[.bat] file from a command line with the following parameters:
>
> -H [proxy server hostname or ip address]
>
> -P [proxy server port]
>
> -N [nonproxy hosts] (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
>
> -u [username for proxy authentication - if required]
>
> -a [password for proxy authentication - if required]
>
> Example: **jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost**

3. You may find [Mobile Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Recorder-Mobile-Recorder-) service easier than JMeter's built-in proxy.

Comment: I have tried for both proxy settings jmeter with my ip and port and Blazemeter proxy and port. On browser still I am getting proxy connection error message.

Comment: Few days back my proxy server got connected for my Test Plan, even it was working. Now again, whenever I create new proxy server and clicks on "Start" button it showing Root CA certificate for my username created date on 11 Feb. Is that a reason I am not able to connect it again?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, however try deleting `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file from JMeter's /bin folder just in case